# Is it wrong to get the User Id in ngOnIt() method?

Tags: angular

Is it wrong to get the User Id in `ngOnIt()` method like this  `this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;` ?
it says `uid` is undefined when i reload the page, but it works fine after i login or redirected from another component, can anyone help and explain where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this inside a provider/service under a method,

```
getUidName(): string{
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;    
}
```

You would be needing the above only when items are created, you can call the above method on successful creation of items rather than on ngOninit